# How to get box with rightward arrow symbol in MS word?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office, unicode, latex, symbols

I tried searching all the symbols in character map and in Microsoft word's symbol section for the following symbol but couldn't find it.

Box with rightward arrow:

[image: Box with rightward arrow]

People usually use this for counterfactual claim in logic. In latex we can get it by `\boxright` command. [See this latex question(not necessary)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/139546/is-there-a-logic-symbol-for-counterfactuals).

My question is is there any way we can have this symbol in Microsoft word?
Is there any Unicode equivalent of it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Is there any Unicode equivalent of it?

You would have to combine a couple of Unicode characters:

Unicode Character 'BALLOT BOX' (U+2610) `☐` or
Unicode Character 'WHITE MEDIUM SQUARE' (U+25FB) `◻`

With:

Browser Test Page for Unicode Character 'RIGHTWARDS ARROW' (U+2192) `→`

Combined:

`☐→` or `◻→`

You might want a Unicode Character 'ZERO WIDTH SPACE' (U+200B) between them

Sources:

- [Browser Test Page for Unicode Character 'BALLOT BOX' (U+2610)](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2610/browsertest.htm)
- [Browser Test Page for Unicode Character 'WHITE MEDIUM SQUARE' (U+25FB)](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/25FB/browsertest.htm)
- [Browser Test Page for Unicode Character 'RIGHTWARDS ARROW' (U+2192)](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2192/browsertest.htm)

Comment: I accepted this answer because it helps but I guess then there is no exact equivalent of that latex character. I mean even after using the 'ZERO WIDTH SPACE' character, there is a slight gap between the box and the arrow which should be avoided

Comment: @Earmen type both characters in MS Word, select them, go to Home -> Fonts -> Advanced, set the spacing to Condensed, then in increase the spacing in the By box until box characters are combined.